# How can i use eval function

Tags: javascript, eval, calculator

I am creating calculator with Javascript and i have a problem with eval() function
HTML
`

```
        <div class="calCul1">
            <div id="firstCol">
                <div id="wind"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="secondCol">
                <div class="buttonsCol1">
                    <div id="underCol1">
                        <div id="bracketOpen"><button id="bracketOBut" onclick=" ">!</button></div>
                        <div id="seven"><button id="sevenBut" onclick="add(7)">7</button></div>
                        <div id="four"><button id="fourBut" onclick="add(4)">4</button></div>
                        <div id="one"><button id="oneBut" onclick="add(1)">1</button></div>
                        <div id="zero"><button id="zeroBut" onclick="add(0)">0</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="underCol2">
                        <div id="bracketClose"><button id="root" onclick=" "add>√</button></div>
                        <div id="eight"><button id="eightBut" onclick="add(8)">8</button></div>
                        <div id="five"><button id="fiveBut" onclick="add(5)">5</button></div>
                        <div id="two"><button id="twoBut" onclick="add(2)">2</button></div>
                        <div id="dote"><button id="doteBut" onclick="addDote('.')">.</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttonsCol2">
                    <div id="underCol3">
                        <div id="procent"><button id="procentBut" onclick="procent('%')">%</button></div>
                        <div id="nine"><button id="nineBut" onclick="add(9)">9</button></div>
                        <div id="six"><button id="sixBut" onclick="add(6)">6</button></div>
                        <div id="three"><button id="threeBut" onclick="add(3)">3</button></div>
                        <div id="equals"><button id="equalsBut" onclick="equal('=')">=</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="underCol4">
                        <div id="delete"><button id="deleteBut" onclick="document.getElementById('wind').innerHTML=''">AC</button></div>
                        <div id="divide"><button id="divideBut" onclick="add('/')">÷</button></div>
                        <div id="multiply"><button id="multiplyBut"  onclick="add('*')">x</button></div>
                        <div id="minuse"><button id="minuseBut"  onclick="add('-')">-</button></div>
                        <div id="plus"><button id="plusBut"  onclick="add('+')">+</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

`
there is no reaction when i click on "+"
Javascript

```
let x = document.getElementById("wind");
function add(a) {
  // document.getElementById("wind").value =
  x.innerHTML += a;
}
function equal() {
  // x.style.cssText = `d`
  x = eval(x);
  // console.log(x);
}
```

i tried to solve it with .value, but then I couldnt even print the numbers

Comment: `eval` is evil.

Comment: "There is no reaction" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Usually, JS can be debugged pretty well in all current browsers

Comment: @NicoHaase No reaction, that is, no reaction

The program does not show the result of summation, multiplication, etc.

Comment: Works fine: `x = eval(x.innerText); console.log(x);`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes, it works, but now i have an error

Comment: As far as I read your code, clicking the `+` button won't calculate anything. So what's the expected behaviour then?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')
    at equal (script.js:8:14)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:61:59)

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important details

Comment: @NicoHaase okay, sry, i am new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here: `x = eval(x);`. You are just getting all of the object. In your code, the `x` variable means that the Document method `getElementById()`. It returns an element object. You should get the element's value, not all of its. Because of that, we use the element property `innerHTML`. the `innerHTML` property gets or sets the HTML or XML within the element.

Hope it helps! In addition: [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

```js
let x = document.getElementById("wind");
function add(a) {
  // document.getElementById("wind").value =
  x.innerHTML += a;
}
function equal() {
  // x.style.cssText = `d`
  x.innerHTML = eval(x.innerHTML);
  // console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<div class="calCul1">
            <div id="firstCol">
                <div id="wind"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="secondCol">
                <div class="buttonsCol1">
                    <div id="underCol1">
                        <div id="bracketOpen"><button id="bracketOBut" onclick=" ">!</button></div>
                        <div id="seven"><button id="sevenBut" onclick="add(7)">7</button></div>
                        <div id="four"><button id="fourBut" onclick="add(4)">4</button></div>
                        <div id="one"><button id="oneBut" onclick="add(1)">1</button></div>
                        <div id="zero"><button id="zeroBut" onclick="add(0)">0</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="underCol2">
                        <div id="bracketClose"><button id="root" onclick=" "add>√</button></div>
                        <div id="eight"><button id="eightBut" onclick="add(8)">8</button></div>
                        <div id="five"><button id="fiveBut" onclick="add(5)">5</button></div>
                        <div id="two"><button id="twoBut" onclick="add(2)">2</button></div>
                        <div id="dote"><button id="doteBut" onclick="addDote('.')">.</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttonsCol2">
                    <div id="underCol3">
                        <div id="procent"><button id="procentBut" onclick="procent('%')">%</button></div>
                        <div id="nine"><button id="nineBut" onclick="add(9)">9</button></div>
                        <div id="six"><button id="sixBut" onclick="add(6)">6</button></div>
                        <div id="three"><button id="threeBut" onclick="add(3)">3</button></div>
                        <div id="equals"><button id="equalsBut" onclick="equal('=')">=</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="underCol4">
                        <div id="delete"><button id="deleteBut" onclick="document.getElementById('wind').innerHTML=''">AC</button></div>
                        <div id="divide"><button id="divideBut" onclick="add('/')">÷</button></div>
                        <div id="multiply"><button id="multiplyBut"  onclick="add('*')">x</button></div>
                        <div id="minuse"><button id="minuseBut"  onclick="add('-')">-</button></div>
                        <div id="plus"><button id="plusBut"  onclick="add('+')">+</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to run the `eval()` function on the text of the `wind` element - i.e `x.innerText` - instead of on the element itself - which is what `eval(x)` is doing.

Also, using `eval()` to perform arithmetic is a really bad idea.